# Error when importing shapefile as vector layer into GRASS GIS

Tags: shapefile, grass-gis, sqlite, grass-7.4

I'm tried to importing an Esri shapefile into GRASS GIS using  both `v.in.ogr` and `v.in.import` however methods fail with the following error message:

```
WARNING: Table <roadsSriLanka> linked to vector map <roadsSriLanka> does
         not exist
Creating attribute table for layer <edges>...
DBMI-SQLite driver error:
Error in sqlite3_prepare():
near "from": syntax error

DBMI-SQLite driver error:
Error in sqlite3_prepare():
near "from": syntax error

ERROR: Unable to create table: 'create table roadsSriLanka (cat integer,
       access varchar ( 80 ), bridge varchar ( 80 ), from varchar ( 80 ),
       highway varchar ( 80 ), junction varchar ( 80 ), key varchar ( 80 ),
       landuse varchar ( 80 ), lanes varchar ( 80 ), length varchar ( 80 ),
       maxspeed varchar ( 80 ), name varchar ( 161 ), oneway varchar ( 80
       ), osmid varchar ( 231 ), ref varchar ( 80 ), service varchar ( 80
       ), to varchar ( 80 ), tunnel varchar ( 80 ), width varchar ( 80 ))'
```

This shapefile was downloaded using the OSMnx Python package. I used another file which I downloaded using the same which imported without an issue

Comment: Your shapefile seems to have an attribute "from" that is a reserved keyword for SQL. GRASS should generate a bit different SQL with double quotation marks `create table (... "from" varchar (80),`. That may be considered as a bug but it requires more research. As a workaround try to rename the attribute into for example `x_from`.

Comment: Thank you @user30184. This solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the error message the failure occurs when GRASS (or GDAL/OGR) is trying to create a SQLite table. The SQL create table statement is included in the message, and the error is pointed to happen somewhere near to "from".

The case can be simplified into

```
CREATE TABLE foo (from);
```

The command will fail and throw the error message `near "from": syntax error` because `from` is a reserved keyword in SQL and it can't be used as an attribute name with that syntax. See [the list of 140 currently reserved keywords in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

The create table statement would work if the reserved keyword was enclosed between double quotation marks for making it into quoted identifier

```
CREATE TABLE foo ("from");
```

Because you can't change the behavior of GRASS or GDAL without changing the program code the best you can do is to use a workaround and rename the offending shapefile attribute "from" into some not reserved name, like "x_from".